# how can I get the names in this html code by python?

Tags: python, html, css, beautifulsoup

[I want to get both of names "Justin Cutroni" and "Krista Seiden" without the tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eww1x.png)

this is my html code that I want to get the names by python3:

I used `beautifulsoup` but I don't know how to get deep in the html codes and get the names.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

web_pages = ["https://maktabkhooneh.org/learn/"]

def find_lessons(web_page):
    # Load the webpage content
    r = requests.get(web_page)
    # Convert to a beautiful soup object
    soup = bs(r.content, features="html.parser")
    table = soup.select('div[class="course-card__title"]')
    data = [x.text.split(';')[-1].strip() for x in table]
    return data

find_teachers(web_pages[0])
```

Comment: Use the developer tools and find the XPath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at `course-card__title`, when it appears you want is `course-card__teacher`.  When you're using `requests`, it's often more useful to look at the real HTML (using `wget` or `curl`) rather than the object model, as in your image.

What you have pretty much works with that change:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

web_pages = ["https://maktabkhooneh.org/learn/"]

def find_teachers(web_page):
    # Load the webpage content
    r = requests.get(web_page)
    soup = bs(r.content, features="html.parser")
    table = soup.select('div[class="course-card__teacher"]')
    return [x.text.strip() for x in table]

print(find_teachers(web_pages[0]))
```

Comment: thanks for your help
I use this code to get the price of the lessons but it doesn't work !
can help me with this one too 
`
def find_prices(web_page):
    r = requests.get(web_page)
    soup = bs(r.content, features="html.parser")
    table = soup.select('div[class="course-card-extra__price"]')
    print([x.text.strip() for x in table])
`

Comment: You need to ask a separate question for this, because it's unrelated.  There is no price in the HTML on that page.  You have to fetch that separate, from the data-url in the wrapping `<div>`.  It's more complicated.